# Can't use msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail when in service broker - executes as guest?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions, service-broker, signature

I have a procedure `TheNotificationProcedure` that makes a cross-database call to msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail.

It gets invoked (indirectly) from a service broker queue:

```
CREATE QUEUE [Blah].[TheQueue]
WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = ON, PROCEDURE_NAME = [Blah].[TheQueueProcedure], 
MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, EXECUTE AS N'TheUser');
```

`TheQueueProcedure` eventually calls `TheNotificationProcedure`

If I connect in SSMS as `TheUser` and execute `TheNotificationProcedure`, everything works and emails go out.

However, when `TheNotificationProcedure` is invoked as a result of a message arriving on the queue, it fails as unable to access the msdb procedure.

I've tried everything I can think of, including creating my own procedure in msdb that wraps sp_send_dbmail and signing both my dbmail wrapper and `TheNotificationProcedure` with the same certiface, and ensure the certificate user in msdb is a member of "DatabaseMailUserRole".

Finally, after doing many more detailed traces, I eventually noticed the following:

[image: Service Broker Trace]

That is even though the service broker is executing under the *login* of `TheUser`, for some reason, it is executing under the database *user* of `guest`, which I suspect at least partially explains my permissions issues.

The *login* `TheUser` is also mapped to a *user* in msdb called `TheUser` - it is certainly not mapped to guest.

So why is it being executed as guest in msdb when going through service broker?

I need to avoid marking the database as `Trustworthy`.  I  was hoping that by signing the procedures (e.g. http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) I could get permissions to transfer across the database - does `execute as` negate any permissions that would typically be associated via the certificate user?

Here is a script to duplicate the above permissions issue *without* any of the module signing (which gives the same "guest" trace) when going through service broker:

Setup:

```
--REPLACE EMAIL, and db_mail profile
--@profile_name = 'Test db mail profile',
--@recipients = 'test@test.test',

use master;
GO

IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.databases where name='http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    ALTER DATABASE [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033] SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033];
END

CREATE DATABASE [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033];
GO

IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'TheUser' AND type_desc='SQL_LOGIN') DROP LOGIN TheUser;

CREATE LOGIN [TheUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'jL839lIFKttcm3cNuk1WUazfk5lS76RKMscZ01UdFkI='
    , DEFAULT_DATABASE=[http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033]
    , DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;

use [msdb];
GO

IF (NOT EXISTS(select * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'TheUser')) CREATE USER [TheUser] FOR LOGIN [TheUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];

exec sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole', 'TheUser';
GO
use [http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166033];
GO

CREATE USER [TheUser] FOR LOGIN [TheUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [Blah] AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE QUEUE [Blah].[SourceQueue];
GO

CREATE SERVICE [//FromService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [Blah].[SourceQueue];
GO

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//TestMessage]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    VALIDATION = NONE;
GO

CREATE CONTRACT [//ServiceContract]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ([//TestMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Blah].[SendMessage]
AS
DECLARE @message varchar(50),
        @conversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

    SET    @message = 'Test Message Content';

    -- Begin the dialog.
    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @conversationHandle
        FROM SERVICE [//FromService]
        TO SERVICE '//ToService'
        ON CONTRACT [//ServiceContract] 
        WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

    -- Send the message on the dialog.
    SEND ON CONVERSATION @conversationHandle
      MESSAGE TYPE [//TestMessage]
      (@message) ;

    END CONVERSATION @conversationHandle ;
GO


CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[TheNotificationProcedure]
AS
    PRINT 'DEBUG - Entering [dbo].[TheNotificationProcedure]'

    -- Send notification
    PRINT 'DEBUG - [dbo].[TheNotificationProcedure] - PRIOR TO msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail'

    declare @log nvarchar(max) = ''; 
    select @log = @log + 'name: ' + name + ' ' + 'type: ' + type + ' usage: ' + usage + ' || ' FROM sys.login_token 
    print @log

    declare @mailitem_id int;

    --exec [msdb].[dbo].[WRAP__sp_send_dbmail]
    exec [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]
                @profile_name = 'Test db mail profile',
                @recipients = 'test@test.test', --@Recipient,
                @subject = 'Testing sp_send_dbmail', --@NotificationSubject,
                @body = 'Testing sp_sdend_dbmail from service broker', --@NotificationBody,
                @exclude_query_output = 1,
                @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id OUTPUT

    PRINT 'DEBUG - [dbo].[TheNotificationProcedure] - AFTER msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail'

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Blah].[TestMessageHandler]
AS
    --has other logic that eventully calls notification
    EXECUTE [dbo].[TheNotificationProcedure]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Blah].[TheQueueProcedure]
AS
--Service Broker variables
DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @conversation_group_id  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @message_body varchar(255),
        @message_type_name NVARCHAR(256),
        @dialog UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @RowsReceived    int

PRINT 'Start'
    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN

        -- Get next conversation group.

        WAITFOR(
           GET CONVERSATION GROUP @conversation_group_id FROM [Blah].[TheQueue]),
           TIMEOUT 500 ;

        -- If there are no more conversation groups, roll back the
        -- transaction and break out of the outermost WHILE loop.

        IF @conversation_group_id IS NULL
        BEGIN
            BREAK ;
        END ;

        WHILE (1 = 1)
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            PRINT 'Get Message'
            ;        RECEIVE TOP (1) 
                            @dialog = conversation_handle,
                            @message_type_name=message_type_name,
                            @message_body=message_body
                    FROM    [Blah].[TheQueue]
                    WHERE conversation_group_id = @conversation_group_id ;

            SET    @RowsReceived = @@ROWCOUNT
            PRINT 'Queue Read: ' + ISNULL(@message_body, '<NULL>')
            PRINT '@RowsReceived: ' + CAST(@RowsReceived as varchar(200))
            IF (@RowsReceived = 0)
                BEGIN
                    BREAK ;
                END ;

            PRINT 'Deal with Message'

            IF (@message_type_name = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'End Dialog received for dialog # ' + cast(@dialog as nvarchar(40)) ;
                END CONVERSATION @dialog ;
            END ;

            IF (@message_type_name = '//TestMessage')
            BEGIN
                print 'Have //TestMessage: ' + @message_body

                exec [Blah].[TestMessageHandler];

            END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

    END
    RETURN

GO





CREATE QUEUE [Blah].[TheQueue]
    WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = ON, PROCEDURE_NAME = [Blah].[TheQueueProcedure], MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, EXECUTE AS N'TheUser');
GO

CREATE SERVICE [//ToService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [Blah].[TheQueue]
    ([//ServiceContract]);
GO


GRANT EXECUTE ON [Blah].[TheQueueProcedure] TO [TheUser];
GO
```

Then to kick everything off:

```
--kick everything off
EXEC [Blah].[SendMessage];

GO

--read results from error log
--(might need to execute once or twice to get results - because service broker is asynchronous)
declare @sqlErrorLog table (LogDate datetime, ProcessInfo nvarchar(max), Text nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO @sqlErrorLog EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 

SELECT * FROM @sqlErrorLog
WHERE LogDate >= DATEADD(SECOND, -15, GETDATE()) AND Text NOT LIKE 'CHECKDB%' AND Text NOT LIKE 'Starting up database ''upgrade%' AND Text NOT LIKE '%upgrade%information%' AND TEXT <> 'Error: 9001, Severity: 21, State: 1.'
ORDER BY LogDate
```

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm fairly certain service broker activated stored procedures and/or the queues for the services are impersonated using execute as user and due to the way execute as user works you are limited to impersonation in the scope of the database for that stored procedure and not inherit server level permissions. Because of this, I *believe* you'll need to set the database settings trustworthy to on so that the user context can extend across databases. TBH I hate seeing databases marked trustworthy.

Answer (score 12):

> I need to avoid marking the database as `Trustworthy`.

That is certainly the right attitude to have towards `TRUSTWORTHY`, and yes, this is possible.

> So why is it being executed as guest in msdb when going through service broker?

I had originally thought that the issue was the typical cause of cross-Database problems when using Impersonation: by default, impersonating a Database-level principal (which is all that the `EXECUTE AS` clause, not statement, can do) will be quarantined to the local Database.

However, additional testing and discussion with the O.P. lead to the discovery that this scenario was slightly different. It seems that using Service Broker <del>is one of the *very few* occasions that module signing does not solve all security problems.</del> That is what I *had* thought upon setting up the typical implementation of module signing since it didn't work. So, I tried several things and found that only SQLCLR was able to accomplish this.

Then recently I found a related question, [sa doesn't have permissions to other database through synonyms with the Service Broker](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122216/sa-doesnt-have-permissions-to-other-database-through-synonyms-with-the-service/122221#122221), that referenced a [post by @Remus Rusanu](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/07/call-a-procedure-in-another-database-from-an-activated-procedure/) in which Remus says that this is indeed possible. Figuring that Remsus's example code worked, I concluded that I must have missed some minor detail. And, in reviewing the details, I found a counter-intuitive option being used:

> > alter the procedure to have an EXECUTE AS clause (otherwise the code signing infrastructure does not work)

Usually module signing allows you to *remove* `EXECUTE AS` clauses and statements, but here it is required. And it is required due to Service Broker working within a Database-only security context via an `EXECUTE AS USER =` statement. By adding the `EXECUTE AS` clause to the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, a new security context is created, and it can access the server-level and/or other Databases, which is what the rest of the module signing setup handles.

Sooooo, um, sorry about getting it right, then changing it to be something workable but not ideal due to missing that one piece ;-). BUT, I now have it working the way I originally said that it should work :-). The first set of example code below is the pure T-SQL, module signing approach that works with `TRUSTWORTHY OFF` (now that I added that missing `WITH EXECUTE AS N'dbo'`). I will keep the SQLCLR approach at the bottom since it did work and might could fit some other scenarios better.

> I was hoping that by signing the procedures ... I could get permissions to transfer across the database

You can. I don't think I ever saw your module signing setup, but it could very well be that you missed the one small, atypical option that I had originally missed (that is the key to getting this whole thing working).

> does `execute as` negate any permissions that would typically be associated via the certificate user?

Only if it is the `EXECUTE AS USER` statement (not the `EXECUTE AS` clause of a `CREATE object` statement, nor the `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` statement). In that one case, the security-context is, and can only be, Database-only, and cannot see the server-level or other databases, even with module signing in place. And, as luck would have it, that (i.e. the `EXECUTE AS USER` statement) is exactly what Service Broker is doing in order to execute the activation procedure. So, yes, that is what prevented your initial attempt at module signing from working. AND, the trick to fixing it is to simply add a `WITH EXECUTE AS N'dbo'` clause to the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement for the proc that access another Database. It doesn't matter what User you use, but I found `dbo` to simplist as using `OWNER` gave a warning about needing to re-sign the Stored Procedure if that Owner ever changed. Of course, it is also possible to change the owner of a Database, so I would have expected a warning on my choice as well, but it didn't so I am choosing to ignore that potential nuance for the moment ;-).

### Ideal Solution (T-SQL)

**Main Setup**

```
USE [master];
GO

IF (DB_ID(N'SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Dropping DB: [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]...', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
  ALTER DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  ALTER DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue] SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  DROP DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];
END


RAISERROR(N'Creating DB: [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]...', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
CREATE DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]
  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_SC
  WITH DB_CHAINING OFF,
       TRUSTWORTHY OFF;

ALTER DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]
SET  RECOVERY SIMPLE,
     PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM,
     ENABLE_BROKER;
GO
-------------------------------------------------

USE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [FunStuff] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GO

CREATE USER [BrokerUser] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];

CREATE QUEUE [FunStuff].[SendingQueue];

CREATE SERVICE [//SendingService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [FunStuff].[SendingQueue];

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//AuditMessage]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    VALIDATION = NONE;

CREATE CONTRACT [//AuditContract]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ([//AuditMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [FunStuff].[SendMessage]
(
  @Content NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

  BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
    FROM SERVICE [//SendingService]
    TO SERVICE '//ReceivingService'
    ON CONTRACT [//AuditContract] 
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

  SEND ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
    MESSAGE TYPE [//AuditMessage]
    (@Content) ;

  END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle ;
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmailHandler]
(
  @EmailSubject VARCHAR(255),
  @EmailContent NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
WITH EXECUTE AS N'dbo' -- THIS IS REQUIRED (when used with Service Broker)!!!
AS
  DECLARE @Recipients NVARCHAR(4000) = N'recipient@place.tld';

  EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]
              @profile_name = N'{my_pofile_name}',
              @recipients = @Recipients,
              @subject = @EmailSubject,
              @body = @EmailContent,
              @exclude_query_output = 1;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [FunStuff].[AuditMessageHandler]
(
  @EmailSubject VARCHAR(255),
  @EmailContent NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
  EXECUTE [dbo].[EmailHandler] @EmailSubject, @EmailContent;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [FunStuff].[AuditActivation]
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @ConversationGroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @MessageBody NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @MessageTypeName NVARCHAR(256),
        @RowsReceived INT;

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN

   WAITFOR(
             GET CONVERSATION GROUP @ConversationGroupID
             FROM [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
        ), TIMEOUT 500;

   IF (@ConversationGroupID IS NULL)
   BEGIN
        BREAK;
   END;

   WHILE (2 = 2)
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRANSACTION;

      RECEIVE TOP (1) 
           @ConversationHandle = [conversation_handle],
           @MessageTypeName = [message_type_name],
           @MessageBody = [message_body]
      FROM    [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
      WHERE   CONVERSATION_GROUP_ID = @ConversationGroupID;

      SET @RowsReceived = @@ROWCOUNT;

      IF (@RowsReceived = 0)
      BEGIN
           COMMIT;
           BREAK;
      END;

      IF (@MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
      BEGIN
           END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
      END;

      IF (@MessageTypeName = N'//AuditMessage')
      BEGIN
           EXEC [FunStuff].[AuditMessageHandler] N'Email From Broker test', @MessageBody;
      END;

      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
   END; -- WHILE (2 = 2)


END; -- WHILE (1 = 1)
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [FunStuff].[AuditActivation] TO [BrokerUser];
GO


CREATE QUEUE [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
    WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = ON,
        PROCEDURE_NAME = [FunStuff].[AuditActivation],
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
        EXECUTE AS N'BrokerUser'
       );

CREATE SERVICE [//ReceivingService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
    ([//AuditContract]);
GO
```

**Module Signing steps to make this work**

```
USE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];

CREATE CERTIFICATE [Permission:SendDbMail]
  ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'MyCertificate!MineMineMine!'
  WITH SUBJECT = N'Grant permission to Send DB Mail',
  EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-12-31';

-- Sign the Stored Procedure that accesses another DB
ADD SIGNATURE
  TO [dbo].[EmailHandler]
  BY CERTIFICATE [Permission:SendDbMail]
  WITH PASSWORD = N'MyCertificate!MineMineMine!';

-- Copy the Certificate to [msdb]
DECLARE @PublicKey VARBINARY(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @PublicKey = CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'Permission:SendDbMail'));

SET @SQL = N'
CREATE CERTIFICATE [Permission:SendDbMail]
FROM BINARY = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @PublicKey, 1) + N';';
PRINT @SQL; -- DEBUG

EXEC [msdb].[sys].[sp_executesql] @SQL;


-- Create the Certificate-based User in [msdb]
EXEC [msdb].[sys].[sp_executesql] N'CREATE USER [Permission:SendDbMail]
FROM CERTIFICATE [Permission:SendDbMail];

GRANT AUTHENTICATE TO [Permission:SendDbMail];

PRINT ''Adding Certificate-based User to DB Role [DatabaseMailUserRole]...'';
EXEC sp_addrolemember N''DatabaseMailUserRole'', N''Permission:SendDbMail'';
';
```

**TEST**

```
USE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];

-- execute statement below if there is an error and the queue is disabled:
-- ALTER QUEUE [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue] WITH STATUS = ON, ACTIVATION (STATUS = ON);

EXEC [FunStuff].[SendMessage] @Content = N'Woo hoo!';
```

### Alternate Solution (SQLCLR)

I was also able to get this to work using SQLCLR (and yes, without enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` :-).

**SQLCLR C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlProcedure()]
    public static void ExecSendDbMail([SqlFacet(MaxSize = 255)] SqlString EmailSubject,
                                       SqlString EmailContent)
    {
        using (SqlConnection _Connection = new
                  SqlConnection("Server=(local); Trusted_Connection=true; Enlist=false;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _Command.CommandText = @"dbo.sp_send_dbmail";

                SqlParameter _ParamProfileName =
                             new SqlParameter("profile_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128);
                _ParamProfileName.Value = "{replace_with_your_profile_name}";
                _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamProfileName);

                SqlParameter _ParamRecipients = new
                      SqlParameter("recipients", SqlDbType.VarChar, (int)SqlMetaData.Max);
                _ParamRecipients.Value = "{replace_with_your_recipients}";
                _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamRecipients);

                SqlParameter _ParamSubject =
                          new SqlParameter("subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
                _ParamSubject.Value = EmailSubject.Value;
                _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamSubject);

                SqlParameter _ParamBody = new
                          SqlParameter("body", SqlDbType.NVarChar, (int)SqlMetaData.Max);
                _ParamBody.Value = EmailContent.Value;
                _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamBody);

                SqlParameter _ParamExcludeQueryOutput =
                          new SqlParameter("exclude_query_output", SqlDbType.Bit);
                _ParamExcludeQueryOutput.Value = true;
                _Command.Parameters.Add(_ParamExcludeQueryOutput);


                _Connection.Open();
                _Connection.ChangeDatabase("msdb");

                _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

**SETUP**

```
USE [master];

CREATE DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]
  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC
  WITH DB_CHAINING OFF,
       TRUSTWORTHY OFF;

ALTER DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]
SET  RECOVERY SIMPLE,
     PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM,
     ENABLE_BROKER;
GO

-- Create objects needed to allow for EXTERNAL_ACCESS without TRUSTWORTHY ON:
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [Permission:SendDbMail$Key]
    FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = N'C:\...\NoTrustworthy.dll';
CREATE LOGIN [Permission:SendDbMail$Login]
    FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [Permission:SendDbMail$Key];
GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO [Permission:SendDbMail$Login];
GO
-------------------------------------------------

USE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [NoTrustworthy]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM N'C:\...\NoTrustworthy.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExecSendDbMail]
(
  @EmailSubject NVARCHAR (255),
  @EmailContent NVARCHAR (MAX)
)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [NoTrustworthy].[UserDefinedFunctions].[ExecSendDbMail];
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [FunStuff] AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GO

CREATE USER [BrokerUser] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];

CREATE QUEUE [FunStuff].[SendingQueue];

CREATE SERVICE [//SendingService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [FunStuff].[SendingQueue];

CREATE MESSAGE TYPE [//AuditMessage]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    VALIDATION = NONE;

CREATE CONTRACT [//AuditContract]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ([//AuditMessage] SENT BY INITIATOR);
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [FunStuff].[SendMessage]
(
  @Content NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
        FROM SERVICE [//SendingService]
        TO SERVICE '//ReceivingService'
        ON CONTRACT [//AuditContract] 
        WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

    SEND ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
      MESSAGE TYPE [//AuditMessage]
      (@Content) ;

    END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle ;
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmailHandler]
(
  @EmailSubject VARCHAR(255),
  @EmailContent NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
    -- other logic

    EXEC [dbo].[ExecSendDbMail] @EmailSubject, @EmailContent;
GO


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [FunStuff].[AuditMessageHandler]
(
  @EmailSubject VARCHAR(255),
  @EmailContent NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
    EXECUTE [dbo].[EmailHandler] @EmailSubject, @EmailContent;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [FunStuff].[AuditActivation]
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @ConversationGroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @MessageBody NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @MessageTypeName NVARCHAR(256),
        @RowsReceived INT;

WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN

     WAITFOR(
               GET CONVERSATION GROUP @ConversationGroupID
               FROM [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
          ), TIMEOUT 500;

     IF (@ConversationGroupID IS NULL)
     BEGIN
          BREAK;
     END;

     WHILE (2 = 2)
     BEGIN
          BEGIN TRANSACTION;
          PRINT 'Get Message';

          RECEIVE TOP (1) 
               @ConversationHandle = [conversation_handle],
               @MessageTypeName = [message_type_name],
               @MessageBody = [message_body]
          FROM    [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
          WHERE   CONVERSATION_GROUP_ID = @ConversationGroupID;

          SET @RowsReceived = @@ROWCOUNT;

          IF (@RowsReceived = 0)
          BEGIN
               COMMIT;
               BREAK;
          END;


          IF (@MessageTypeName = 
      N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
          BEGIN
               END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
          END;

          IF (@MessageTypeName = N'//AuditMessage')
          BEGIN
               EXEC [FunStuff].[AuditMessageHandler]
                       N'Email From Broker test', @MessageBody;
          END;

          COMMIT TRANSACTION;
     END; -- WHILE (2 = 2)

END; -- WHILE (1 = 1)
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [FunStuff].[AuditActivation] TO [BrokerUser];
GO



CREATE QUEUE [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
    WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = ON,
        PROCEDURE_NAME = [FunStuff].[AuditActivation],
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
        EXECUTE AS N'BrokerUser'
       );

CREATE SERVICE [//ReceivingService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue]
    ([//AuditContract]);
GO

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**TEST**

```
USE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];

-- execute statement below if there is an error and the queue is disabled:
-- ALTER QUEUE [FunStuff].[ReceivingQueue] WITH STATUS = ON, ACTIVATION (STATUS = ON);

EXEC [FunStuff].[SendMessage] @Content = N'try me!';
```

**CLEANUP**

```
IF (DB_ID(N'SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  RAISERROR(N'Dropping DB: [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue]...', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
  ALTER DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  ALTER DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue] SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  DROP DATABASE [SendDbMailFromServiceBrokerQueue];
END

DROP LOGIN [Permission:SendDbMail$Login];
DROP ASYMMETRIC KEY [Permission:SendDbMail$Key];
```

Comment: Following recommendations 1-4 didn't seem to change anything - still failing, still seeing `guest` in the trace.  Though I'm wondering if there's perhaps some other subtle difference I'm missing between your example and what I have.  I'm going to try taking your example and see if I can run it through service broker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55164/discussion-between-srutzky-and-nathan).

Comment: Thanks Solomon, this helped me too, but holy crap this is nuts, no wonder everyone just uses trustworthy.  In my case I'm trying to access SSISDB from a chain of events coming from an Activation Procedure, it took me well over a day before I found here that you have to use another EXECUTE AS otherwise the signing doesn't work.  My fear though is in my next phase I'm going to run into the issue where start_execution is already doing EXECUTE AS and REVERT, which will be intractable, but stay tuned.

Comment: @MarkSowul Glad this info helped. If you do run into problems in the next phase, let me know and we will figure it out.

Comment: Also if you are using dynamic SQL, something else I ran into was that my activation procedure ultimately calls an inner procedure via dynamic SQL, and it was that inner procedure I had to sign and mark with EXECUTE AS.  I couldn't get it to work by altering the activation procedure itself.  My guess is that this is related to the fact that EXECUTE AS permissions don't carry through dynamic SQL (which is usually one of the advantages to signatures)

Comment: @MarkSowul When you had tried by putting `EXECUTE AS` on only the activation proc (not the proc called within Dynamic SQL), did you have both procs signed with the same certificate, or just the activation proc?

Comment: I have requested that the chat room linked several comments above be unfrozen and our recent comments moved into it, by flagging your comment directly above as "other"..I will delete this comment once the room has been unfrozen...

Comment: The other interesting (and flummoxing) part of this is that the EXECUTE AS user on the procedure is pretty much arbitrary in that the target external database does not need any knowledge of that user (no need for shared login).  So even though the activation procedure is already attached to the queue with  EXECUTE AS 'X', just adding the "seemingly-redundant" WITH EXECUTE AS 'X' to the procedure gets things to work.  It doesn't need to run as any special user per se (e.g. owner or dbo), it's just a trick to override the Service Broker context.  Just another point for the next hapless soul.

Comment: @MarkSowul Thank you very much for pointing out this extra info :-). I will definitely incorporate the fact that the module that accesses the other DB is the one that needs the `EXECUTE AS` in an upcoming post on my blog, in a series about Module Signing where I am showing simple step-by-step guides for the major scenarios, and I still have to do the database-to-database scenario. I had noted the arbitrariness of the `EXECUTE AS` user in the paragraph just above "**Ideal Solution (T-SQL)**", but I will be sure to make that more prominent in the upcoming blog post.

Comment: @MarkSowul Actually, I just reviewed the code in my answer and it seems I'm already showing that it's only the final proc of the chain in the initial DB (i.e. the one with the call to the other DB) that has the `EXECUTE AS`. If you look at the "**Ideal Solution (T-SQL)**" section, under "**Main Setup**" there is a proc, `[dbo].[EmailHandler]`, just after the second line of dashes (`---`). That's the 3rd proc in the chain, and calls `[msdb]`, and has `EXECUTE AS`. But, neither proc #2, `[FunStuff].[AuditMessageHandler]`, nor proc #1, `[FunStuff].[AuditActivation]`, the activation proc, have it.

Comment: So for the moment, it would appear that the Dynamic SQL scenario is not behaving differently than static SQL. And I just noticed that I mentioned in that last paragraph before  "**Ideal Solution**" that it's the proc that makes the call to the other DB that needs `EXECUTE AS`. Sorry, I hadn't looked at this stuff in quite some time ;-). But, now I am wondering what would happen if the call to the other DB were done in Dynamic SQL. Meaning, something like: `EXEC(N'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_something;`);`. Hmmm....

Comment: Thanks Solomon -- yeah, my purpose with the extended commentary is that depending on the exact scenario it can still be easy to get wrong and the error messages are misleading: 1. If you use EXECUTE AS in the "top proc" in the chain (e.g. activation proc itself), that may not be enough if something else isn't signed.  2. If things go wrong, you'll still get "user X can't access database Y in this context", but that doesn't mean database Y actually needs to know anything about user X, it still means something didn't go right with the signing / EXECUTE AS

Comment: "My fear though is in my next phase I'm going to run into the issue where start_execution is already doing EXECUTE AS and REVERT, which will be intractable, but stay tuned".  Yeah :(  As I feared...

"The current security context cannot be reverted. Please switch to the original database where 'Execute As' was called and try it again." ERROR_PROCEDURE="internal.prepare_execution"

Comment: I suppose I'll also go with either the CLR or the 'sql agent reads from a queue' route (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80507).  On the plus side, _creating_ the execution (and setting the parameters) seems to work; it's just _starting_ the execution that seems to fail, so that makes life a lot easier.

Comment: Hi @MarkSowul . Sorry I forgot to reply to reply to your final message on May 17th. I don't fully understand point 2 as the error is accurate, and indicates a problem with the signing since the context shouldn't be "user X". I also don't understand the issue with `REVERT`. True, `REVERT` can only be executed in the DB in which impersonation was started, but you can't revert the `EXECUTE AS` clause, only the statement, but why would you be using the statement? And why are you trying to revert? I'm wondering if you should post this as a separate question because there are some missing details.

Comment: No worries.  The error is accurate, yes - but for someone who is trying to get the signing to work, I just wanted to emphasize precisely what you point out: if you get that message, it is because the signing isn't working, it doesn't imply that user 'x' needs any particular permissions -- I want to make clear (to any reader who hasn't gotten it working yet and may be wondering) -- when done right, none of the other users involved (e.g. the one executing the procedure) need to have any access to the target database.  Only the signing user.

Comment: There are two EXECUTE AS: one in the "WITH" clause of my procedure (needed for service broker activation to work with signing), and apparently (based on findings in e.g. the linked question and elsewhere) a flawed setup with the EXECUTE AS _statement_ (and then a REVERT) within the internals of ssisdb.start_execution that causes things not to work right when trying to call start_execution from another database (by signing the calling procedure).

Comment: For example this is an MSDN forum thread on the same topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/11952f29-f4db-4adc-b813-efd9bed09df3/ssisdb-createexecution-error-the-current-security-context-cannot-be-reverted-please-switch-to-the

Comment: @MarkSowul I reviewed that MSDN forum thread and a related thread linked in one of it's posts, and yikes, there is definitely some misinformation / confusion going on there regarding how `REVERT` works. I will try to do a post next week on it, but for now, do you know exactly where the `REVERT` is being called? I don't use SSIS so I don't have `ssisdb.start_execution`. I suppose I could install it, but I don't have time for that right now.

Comment: Inside the (built-in) ssisdb.catalog.start_execution procedure (not marked with an EXECUTE AS clause), there is a block of code that does `EXECUTE AS CALLER (do stuff) REVERT`.  My understanding is that this is flawed because in the absence of an EXECUTE AS clause on the procedure, or some other EXECUTE AS statement prior, using EXECUTE AS CALLER doesn't actually have an effect, so the REVERT doesn't actually affect the EXECUTE AS CALLER.  But of course if the _caller_ of start_execution is using impersonation in any way, then the REVERT is trying to operate on that and fails.

Comment: @MarkSowul Yes, that is exactly the issue. I posted to the other thread that I confirmed that a job does in fact use Impersonation if owned by a non-sysadmin user, and that would have to be via EXECUTE AS _statement_, not _clause_, hence can be reverted...and yes, the `EXECUTE AS CALLER` statement in that proc is 100% useless..

Answer (score 1):

I post here my founds around this problem.
My first answer was this one:

- create the certificate in `master` and create a login from it;
- map this login to `msdb` and include the corrensponding user in `DatabaseMailUserRole`
- export the certificate to your user database
- sign your activation proc with this certificate

Even before I could try it, Solomon Rutzky gave me the link to this answer and I also suspected that I'll get DENY ONLY to `DatabaseMailUserRole` membership, and so it happened:

[image]

The picture above shows my proc and how it's executed by user test.
It's important to understand that the procedure (activation proc in particular) will be always executed as **user**, not login, that is by design: [Internal Activation Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171585(v=sql.105).aspx)

> A queue configured for activation must also specify **the user that
>   the activation stored procedure runs as**. SQL Server impersonates
>   this **user** before starting the stored procedure.

So I execute it by user test that has no login, I created it this way:

```
create user test without login
```

Ok, I saw what was expected: my signed proc has recieved membership in `DatabaseMailUserRole` but with `DENY ONLY`.

Now I can return to the OP's question:

> That is even though the service broker is executing **under the login of
>   TheUser**, for some reason, it is executing under the database user of
>   guest, which I suspect at least partially explains my permissions
>   issues.
>
> The login TheUser is also mapped to a user in msdb called TheUser - it
>   is certainly not mapped to guest.
>
> **So why is it being executed as guest in msdb when going through
>   service broker?**

The error is here: activation proc is NOT executed under the **login**. It always executed under the **user**.

That is why I even don't need to set up Service Broker, queue, activation proc...It's enough to make the test with a simple proc uxecuted by **user**

And now the finally part. To make my solution work I need the last condition to be true: user database must be `TRUSTWORTHY` with the owner that has `AUTHENTICATE SERVER` permission.
This way the **certificate user** will be able to go out of his sandbox-database, it will not be a `guest` in `msdb` but it will be certificate user:

[image]

I don't think it's a good solution, I'm always against making user database `TRUSTWORTHY`.

**It's safe only when that user database has no `db_owner` that is not a `sysadmin` at the same time**

P.S. I upvote **Solomon Rutzky** solution that don't touch `TRUSTWORTHY` at all.

Comment: Hey there. I just updated my answer above with the actual, correct implementation of the module signing approach. I explain what I got wrong on my initial attempt. But the whole thing works without using `TRUSTWORTHY ON` and without using SQLCLR. This is what I had meant by "I think I found something that I need to test" in my comment on your now deleted answer to that recent duplicate question.